# Error while enabling camel-swagger-java at karaf startup

Tags: apache-camel, karaf

**Problem**

I'm trying to install the camel feature **camel-swagger-java 2.22.2** in a **karaf 4.2.2** environment.

I added the feature *camel-swagger-java* to *featuresBoot* property in the config file *etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg* of karaf because I want that this feature is installed when karaf is up.

When I launch *bin/karaf* I get this error:

> org.apache.karaf.features.internal.util.MultiException: Error:
>           Error downloading wrap:file:/C:/Users/karaf/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-parser/1.0.36/swagger-parser-1.0.36.jar
>           Error downloading wrap:file:/C:/Users/karaf/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-parser/1.0.36/swagger-parser-1.0.36.jar
>           at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager$MavenDownloader.(MavenDownloadManager.java:91)
>           at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadManager.createDownloader(MavenDownloadManager.java:72)
>           at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:457)
>           at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.Subsystem.downloadBundles(Subsystem.java:452)
>           at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:224)
>           at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:388)
>           at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1025)
>           at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:964)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>           Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Error downloading wrap:file:/C:/Users/karaf/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-parser/1.0.36/swagger-parser-1.0.36.jar
>                   at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:77)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>                   ... 3 more
>           Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not download [wrap:file:/C:/Users/karaf/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-parser/1.0.36/swagger-parser-1.0.36.jar]
>                   at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.SimpleDownloadTask.download(SimpleDownloadTask.java:91)
>                   at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:60)
>                   ... 7 more
>           Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: wrap
>                   at java.net.URL.(URL.java:627)
>                   at java.net.URL.(URL.java:490)
>                   at java.net.URL.(URL.java:439)
>                   at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.SimpleDownloadTask.download(SimpleDownloadTask.java:62)
>                   ... 8 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: wrap
>                   at org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.parseURL(URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.java:373)
>                   at java.net.URL.(URL.java:622)
>                   ... 11 more
>           [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.io.IOException: Error downloading wrap:file:/C:/Users/karaf/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-parser/1.0.36/swagger-parser-1.0.36.jar

---

**Code**

These are the first lines of my *etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg*

> featuresRepositories mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise/4.2.2/xml/features, mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring/4.2.2/xml/features, mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.2.2/xml/features, mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/framework/4.2.2/xml/features, mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.22.2/xml/features, mvn:org.apache.karaf.decanter/apache-karaf-decanter/2.1.0/xml/features, mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-features/1.3.2/xml/features, mvn:org.apache.servicemix.features/servicemix-features/7.0.1/xml/features
>
> **featuresBoot** = instance/4.2.2, package/4.2.2, log/4.2.2, ssh/4.2.2, framework/4.2.2, system/4.2.2, eventadmin/4.2.2, feature/4.2.2, shell/4.2.2, management/4.2.2, service/4.2.2, jaas/4.2.2, deployer/4.2.2, diagnostic/4.2.2, wrap/2.5.4, bundle/4.2.2, config/4.2.2, kar/4.2.2, webconsole/4.2.2, jdbc/4.2.2, http/4.2.2, jetty/4.2.2, camel/2.22.2, camel-core/2.22.2, camel-blueprint/2.22.2, camel-spring/2.22.2, camel-jetty/2.22.2, camel-netty/2.22.2, camel-netty-http/2.22.2, camel-netty4/2.22.2, camel-netty4-http/2.22.2, camel-http4/2.22.2, camel-jackson/2.22.2, camel-sql/2.22.2, camel-jdbc/2.22.2, camel-quartz/2.22.2, camel-jacksonxml/2.22.2, **camel-swagger-java/2.22.2**, decanter-appender-elasticsearch-rest/2.1.0, decanter-collector-log/2.1.0, pax-jdbc-mariadb/1.3.2, pax-jdbc-mysql/1.3.2, pax-jdbc-config/1.3.2

---

**Question**

Why I get this error? It's a bug of camel-swagger-java feature or I'm missing something?

Comment: Maybe try with Camel 2.22.4

Comment: Same error with Camel 2.22.4

Comment: AFAIR there is some karaf bundle that has the `wrap` functionality. So maybe look whether its in the features boot also.

Comment: Yes you're right. If I remove from bootFeature `camel-swagger-java` and I install manually this feature after karaf is up: I get an error (but it works) and I see in the bundles list that `swagger-parser` is wrapped from .m2 repository. But how can I do if I start a brand new instance of karaf (with an empty .m2 repository) and I want that `camel-swagger-java` is automatically enabled at karaf startup? I don't know how to install the single bundle `swagger-parser` at boot time. Is there a way to skip this error at karaf boot time? because this error freezing the karaf initialization.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I've been struggling with this, too. Karaf 4.2.4 & Camel 3.0.0-M1. I don't know what to do with this error message.

Comment: At the moment no solution. I tried the most recent version of karaf 4.2.5 and Camel 3.0.0-M2 without results.